# Count number of repeat rows after multi join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables that I need to retrieve info from:  Products, ProductOptions, and OptionChoices.  As of now this is the SQL I am using to get said information

```
select P.ProductId,P.Name,P.StoreId,PO.OptionId,OC.ChoiceName from Products P
inner join ProductOptions PO on P.ProductId=PO.ProductID
inner join OptionChoices OC on PO.OptionId=OC.OptionId
where P.ProductId=23317
```

which outputs this:

```
ProductId   Name               StoreID OptionId ChoiceName
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     795      fish
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     795      shrimp
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     795      traps
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     797      box
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     797      casket
```

What would make my life a lot easier is if I could add one more column that would give me the total number of Choices for Each OptionId.  So the first row would read:

```
ProductId   Name               StoreID OptionId ChoiceName  Count
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     795      fish         3
```

Because there are 3 Choices with 795 as their OptionIds.  I've tried using different combinations of group by and count, but have had no luck.  Anyone have any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Edit:
I am using SQL Server

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: SQL server.  Just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate query to count up the options.  In this MS SQL SERVER example I've use a correlated sub-query to do the counting.

```
SELECT
  P.ProductId,
  P.Name,
  P.StoreId,
  PO.OptionId,
  OC.ChoiceName,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OptionChoices WHERE OptionId = OC.OptionId) AS option_count
FROM
  Products   P
INNER JOIN
  ProductOptions PO
    ON P.ProductId = PO.ProductID
INNER JOIN
  OptionChoices  OC
    ON PO.OptionId = OC.OptionId    
WHERE
  P.ProductId=23317
```

Comment: That totally worked. Thanks!  I am going to spend some time reading this query to figure it out.

Comment: The performance 'problems' will entirely depend on indexing and the size of the data set in question.  As this query has `P.ProductId=23317`, the correlated sub query will only really be relevant to a small number of records.  Also, note that SQL Server is pretty good at optimising this.  That said, joining on `(SELECT OptionID, COUNT(*) FROM OptionChoices GROUP BY OptionID)` will be faster for larger data sets.

Comment: This isn't for anything production related.  I need to generate some reports and this just helps me get the task done faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-)

```
select P.ProductId,P.Name,P.StoreId, PO.OptionId, max(OC.ChoiceName), count(P.ProductId) from Products P
inner join ProductOptions PO on P.ProductId=PO.ProductID
inner join OptionChoices OC on PO.OptionId=OC.OptionId
where P.ProductId=23317
GROUP BY P.ProductId, PO.OptionId
```

the Problem is that you dont know what you get for field "OC.ChoiceName" - you can also use GROUP_CONCAT(OC.ChoiceName)

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Result for max:

```
ProductId   Name               StoreID OptionId ChoiceName  Count
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     795      traps        3
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     797      box          2
```

Result for GROUP_CONCAT (only MySQL!!):

```
ProductId   Name               StoreID OptionId ChoiceName           Count
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     795      fish,shrimp,traps      3
23317   Admiral Ackbar Cereal   629     797      box,casket             2
```

Comment: Bummer, getting errors for each.  For the first: Column 'Products.ProductId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
For the Second: Incorrect syntax near 'GROUP_CONCAT'.  Using Sql server if that helps

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is MySQL - Sorry - forgot "P." and "PO." in "GROUP BY" - try again

Answer (score 1):

You are so close...

Do:

```
Select p.Productid, p.name,     
P.storeid,P.optionid, Count(choicename) 
From ( your actual query here) p
Group by p.productid,p.name,p.storeid,p.optionid
```

Comment: That drops the option_name from the result set.  The OP wants each record, together with the count of records in the group...

Comment: Column 'OptionChoices.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Dear SO'ers, I wrote my statement from a cell and it's kind of difficult to see the whole thing in the mobile version, if option_name is wanted, then should be selected; if repeated values are not desired, then it shoul be grouped by that column. The idea is to select all columns that Repeat themselves and do count of the ones that don't repeat, grouping by all the ones that are not enclosed in a count.

Comment: The OP wants each item in the set, without GROUPing, de-duplication, or any other functionality.  Then, as an additional field, the count of the sub-group is needed.  This can't be achieved with just one reference to the OptionChoices table.

Comment: @dems my mistake then, I thought he only wanted distinct columns + a count of choices for same product.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      P.ProductId
    , P.Name
    , P.StoreId
    , PO.OptionId
    , OC.ChoiceName
    , count(PO.OptionId) over (partition by P.StoreId) as OpCount
from Products P
inner join ProductOptions PO on P.ProductId = PO.ProductID
inner join OptionChoices OC  on PO.OptionId = OC.OptionId
where P.ProductId = 23317
```